# MySQL: Filter group view vs. inline select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, view, group-by

i am just curious about performance of a summarize query on a mysql (5.5) database.

i have a table: `timestamp | category | value`.

now i try to

1. round timestamp to 5min of an hour
2. filter by timestamp for a day (very selective)
3. group with rounded timestamp and category and make the average of value

is it **cheaper** for the database server to **1)** build the sql dynamically or **2)** to make a view which does the group by and filter afterwards for the day?

my working solution is now **1)** but i like the idea **2)** from maintenance point of view more.

Or maybe someone can point me out a free, fast solution to compare the cost of both possibilities.

many thanks in advance & best regards,
martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way will be to filter down to one day and then do the work.

This is something like this:

```
select date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H'), floor(minute(timestamp) / 12),
       category, avg(value)
from t
where timestamp >= '2015-01-01' and timestamp < '2015-01-02'
group by date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H'), floor(minute(timestamp) / 12)
order by min(timestamp);
```

Note the `where` clause.  It is using an inequality, so you can use an index on `t(timestamp)`.

Comment: This is exactly what i am doing now, thank you @gordon, just as an info, i convert the timestamp to **unix timestamp** (since its actual date) make a modulo on it and convert back. i have the feeling this is better performance for the **group by**.

Comment: @martin . . . The group by is so dominated by the file sort that I don't think a bit of data arithmetic -- one way or the other -- really makes a difference.